# What is the proper way to make position restriction for several QGraphicsItem elements on scene?

Tags: c++, qt, position, qgraphicsitem

I have custom scene and it is implemented as a class derived from QGraphicsScene. 
Also there are some QGraphicsItem-based items on it. I want to make the restriction to the scene coordinates in what these items can be moved.

So I implement itemChange() mеthod in these classes derived from QGraphicsItem class. As a result when I select multiple items on scene and move them to the defined scene bounds every item stop moving near this bound and all moved items constrict in one point. 
I want to move all selected items as one item so when one item is near the scene bounds moving of other items stops.

So I decided to use QGraphicsItemGroup approach. In my custom scene class I create group of all selected item in mouseMoveEvent, make group rect position traсking and in the mouseReleaseEvent I destroy the group.
But after that all my items become not movable.
How can I handle this?

Comment: I looked into QGraphicsItem and QGraphicsScene source code.
I found that implementation of QGraphicsItemGroup methods is no so good and 
adding items to group breaks my implementation.

Comment: I decided to use a private field in my custom scene class like
QMap<QGraphicsItem *, QPointF> _itemsLastAllowedPositions
(like at QGraphicsScene class)
that holds all selected items and their last allowed positions.

I create this map when the moving just begun (e.g. in slot connected to the selectionChanged signal
or in mousePressEvent method) and update items positions in mouseMoveEvent.
When items get outside the allowed scene rect the movement stops.
At mouseReleaseEvent positions of all selected items (equally the positions of all items in the map) will be set to last allowed position.

Comment: But as I understand, both mouseMoveEvent method is called often and selectionChanged signal emitted often during move and this course some delay in items move.
Does this approach good in this case?
Is there any other better solution of my problem?